# Editing CSS in Gwt WindowBuilder

Tags: css, eclipse, gwt, windowbuilder

I am using GWT in a project and recently started using the WindowBuilder in Eclipse.  I created a new class and in the WindowBuilder and added some widgets.  All that works and everything.  However, when I try to edit the CSS for some of the panels and I click to edit the "styleName" field I get an error message which says:

```
"There are no CSS files referenced from modules HTML."
```

I've tried adding a link to a style sheet in my base html file and in the Web.gwt.xml file, but that does not seem to work.  I get the same error.

In other classes I have used UiBinder and added the style in the XML file, but this class doesn't use UiBinder.  So how do I associate a CSS file with the class so that the WindowBuilder allows me to edit the style?

In this project I don't have or use a "war" directory.  The project is a couchapp, so I compile it to another directory and push it to CouchDB from there.  It seems that in other projects, where there is the original project setup with a war directory, this feature works properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to work around it by moving my CSS-resources from the war-directory to the classpath, specifically inside a package that is declared as a "public path" inside the GWT module descriptior via "<public path='...' />".

Project layout (odd location for module descriptor because of [Eclipse Plugin Bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1597)):

```
src
|- main
   |- java
   |  |- demo
   |     |- client
   |     |  |- MyWidget.java
   |     |  |- MyWidget.ui.xml
   |     |- Demo.gwt.xml
   |- resources
      |- demo
         |- css
            |- Demo.css
```

Demo.gwt.xml:

```
<module>
         ...
    <source path="client" />
         ...
    <public path="css" />
    <stylesheet src="Demo.css" />
         ...
</module>
```

Comment: Part of the problem may be that I do not use the war directory or the internal Jetty server.  My project is served from CouchDB and so I compile it to another location.

Comment: I tried adding the location of my style-sheet to the public path, but it did not seem to resolve the issue.  I also tried moving the style sheet to various locations, but still nothing.

Comment: I've added my project layout for reference. Make sure your CSS-resources reside below the path declared as 'public'. I'd guess something like "<stylesheet src='../Demo.css' />" wouldn't work.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.  What did work was refreshing the browser window launched through the GWT Dev Mode plugin; I suppose the deployed CSS file was refreshed this way.  Maybe the default layout created through the designer is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem: 
In module file *gwt.xml* type:

```
<stylesheet src="example.css"/>
```

Next in menu: *Project -> clean*.