# Eclipse GWT "There are no CSS files referenced"

Tags: java, css, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 1, instaled the latest GWT Designer plugin and run update. When I am in GWT Design and I select the CSS button in the StyleName row of a widget's properties I get the message "There are no CSS files referenced from module or HTML".

My gwt.xml is:

```
<module>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
<entry-point class="org.AwardTracker.client.AwardTracker"/>
<stylesheet src="org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker.css"/>

<!--  servelet context - path is arbitrary, but must match up with the rpc init inside java class -->
<!--  Tomcat will listen for this from the server and waits for rpc request in this context -->
<servlet class="org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection" path="/MySQLConnection" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark"/>
</module>
```

My CSS is in org.AwardTracker (directly above the gwt.xml file).

All the hints that I have googled have been to update GWT Designer. These hints are all several years old and I have the latest version.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your project packages and references correct. You can follow the solution offered here regarding project/file organization - [Editing CSS in Gwt WindowBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461436/editing-css-in-gwt-windowbuilder)

Comment: You can close the question by selecting the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to first chk your css file in war folder bcoz css file and html file exist in war folder than check link in html file

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css">
```

Comment: Ruchi ,We have to give that link in xml file ??

Comment: yeah.. but also give in html file like i said and in xml file <stylesheet src="standard.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

It seems the file is not found due to the path.You are already in The `xml` file so  try

```
<stylesheet src="AwardTracker.css"/>
```

Hope this will helpfull .